# How to change input field back to text

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, input, html-table

I have a table and a script that makes each cell an input field when clicked on the edit button at the end of a row.
I submit the edited data via Ajax, but I want to make the input field back to normal text after I have edited it.

Here is the code:

```
//// EACH CELL INTO INPUT FIELD ////
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".edit").click(function(){
          var tr = $(this).closest("tr");

          tr.find(".td").each(function(){
              var name = $(this).attr("title");
              var value = $(this).html();
              var input = "<input type='text' name='"+name+"' value='"+value+"' />";
              $(this).html(input);
          });

          var submit = "<input type='button' name='Submit' value='Submit' />";
          tr.find(".button").html(submit);

      });
});
//// END ////

//// ONCLICK SUBMIT SEND DATA VIA AJAX ////
$(".button input[type=button]").live('click', function() {
  var data = $('form#muuda').serialize();
  // post data using ajax                                                                                                                                                                         
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?leht=kast",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Andmed muudetud"); // show response from the php script.                                                                                                                                          
    }
  });
});
//// END ////
```

HTML:

```
<form id="muuda" method="post" action="#">
    <table>

<?PHP
$sql="SELECT * FROM nimed";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
  WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))  {
        echo '<tr class="row">';
            echo '<td class="td" title="id">'.$row["id"].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="td" title="eesnimi">'.$row["eesnimi"].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="td" title="perenimi">'.$row["perenimi"].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="button" title="button"><button class="edit">Edit</button></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
  }
?>

    </table>
</form>
```

Here is a picture of the preview:

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-vVnabdBzFlA/UBjTRhifpWI/AAAAAAAACAo/RvAgpi7x2ik/s488/Ajax%2520submit.jpg

Comment: i used ["Edit In Place"](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/) which is a jQuery plugin where you click on a text and it suddenly becomes a inputtextfield, where you edit the text however you wish, and save the text or recover the old text by using the two buttons "Save" and "Cancel". take a look at [Example 1 on this demo-page](http://jquery-in-place-editor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can just reverse the process you use to turn it from text to an input box:

```
tr.find('.td').each(function () {
    var value  = $(this).find('input').val();
    $(this).html(value);
});
```

You will have to set the variable `tr` to the right row, of course.